# How to route to script of library in vendor folder?

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes, composer-php

I'm writing a PHP library and I want that a specific script is loaded when a specific route is accessed.

For example, when `/login` is requested, I want to load the script `/vendor/MYLIBRARY/login.php`.

I thought about putting a redirect in the htaccess file, but that would be uncomfortable to the user and I think there must be a better way.

I also thought about writing an composer install script that gets called when the user installs my library.

What should I do? And Maybe short description.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try loading the script using relative file path . something like :

require_once(**DIR**.'/../vendor/MYLIBRARY/login.php');

ofcourse edit the path to correct value.